# base64 decoder in android in API level 7

Tags: java, android, base64

How to decode a base64 encoded string to byte array on Android API level 7?

Can it be done using any standard packages of Java?

Should i copy the source code from google search results?

Should i re-implement encoder and decoder according to RFC?

PS: API level 8 has util package android.util.Base64 that does this, but i have to do development based on API level 7.

Comment: or do as suggested in the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4322182/808940

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this class,

```
org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64
```

BouncyCastle is included in Level 7.

Comment: I couldn't find the BouncyCastle in the android.jar packages list at http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html.

Comment: You are right. It wasn't there. We include a BC jar and I thought it came with Android.

Comment: This answer is still useful for those who have already been using BouncyCastle for other purposes.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure if there's n or not, but if there isn't, I wouldn't implement your own, I'd use something like [Mikael Grev's MiGBase64](http://migbase64.sourceforge.net/) which has been extensively tested and (as far as I can see) should work on Android

#### Much later edit

It was added in v8 (android 2.2).  See [`android.util.Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had to use Base64.NO_WRAP on Android to make it match plain Java results

- Plain Java==>DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
  string2Encode.getBytes() );
- Android==>   Base64.encodeToString(
  string2Encode.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP );