# Base64 encoder and decoder

Tags: java, android, base64, encoder, decoder

Is there a base-64 decoder and encoder for a String in Android?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

See [`android.util.Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

It seems that this was added in API version 8 or android 2.2 so it will not be available on the older platforms.

But the source of it is at [`android/util/Base64.java`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/util/Base64.java) so if needed one could just copy it unchanged for older versions.

Comment: encoded Base64 of Mw== is TXc9PQ==
But this source code show TXc9PQo=

What's wrong?! :-o

Comment: @Mr.Hyde You have a trailing new line. TXc9PQo= decodes to `Mw==\n`.

Comment: Yea, and to solve it, we should use Base64.NO_WRAP for flag in encodeToString function, instead of Base64.DEFAULT.

Comment: hi have Base64.class but its having an error "$assertionsDisabled cannot be resolved to a variable"

Answer (score 77):

This is an example of how to use the `Base64` class to encode and decode a simple String value.

```
// String to be encoded with Base64
String text = "Test";
// Sending side
byte[] data = null;
try {
    data = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

// Receiving side
byte[] data1 = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
String text1 = null;
try {
    text1 = new String(data1, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This excerpt can be included in an Android activity.

Comment: using `Base64.DEFAULT` will insert a line break in my case. I use `Base64.NO_WRAP` instead.

Comment: The only one which works for me with 2 bytes characters.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple method I was going to use until I realized that this is only supported in **Android API 8+**:

```
// Has line break
public String getBase64(String input) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(input.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

// No line break
public String getBase64(String input) {
    return Base64.encodeToString(input.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

Comment: as @arvin commented above: "using Base64.DEFAULT will insert a line break in my case. I use Base64.NO_WRAP instead."

Answer (score 12):

#### To encode:

```
private String encodeString(String s) {
    byte[] data = new byte[0];

    try {
        data = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        String base64Encoded = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

        return base64Encoded;

    }
}
```

#### To decode:

```
private String decodeString(String encoded) {
    byte[] dataDec = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);
    String decodedString = "";
    try {

        decodedString = new String(dataDec, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        return decodedString;
    }
}
```

#### Example

```
    String text = "example007";

    Log.e("encoded", encodeString(text)); //Output: ZXhhbXBsZTAwNw==
    Log.e("decoded", decodeString(encodeString(text))); //Output: example007
```

Answer (score 5):

If you **don't** want a **line break** at the end of the String, change the flags from `Base64.DEFAULT` to `Base64.NO_WRAP`

```
Base64.encodeToString("yourString".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin supports Base64 for versions 1.8.20 and over. It has 3 types available which are Base64.Default, Base64.UrlSafe and Base64.Mime.

```
// Base64.Default
val nameBytes = "Nav".map { it.code.toByte() }.toByteArray()
val encodedValue = Base64.Default.encode(nameBytes)
// Encode value: TmF2
println("Encoded: $encodedValue") 
// Decoded value: Nav
println("Decoded: ${String(Base64.Default.decode(encodedValue))}")

// Base64.UrlSafe
val googleIOUrlBytes = "google.io".map { it.code.toByte() }.toByteArray()
// Encode value: Z29vZ2xlLmlv
val encodedURLSafe = Base64.UrlSafe.encode(googleIOUrlBytes)
println("Encoded UrlSafe: $encodedURLSafe")
// Decoded value: google.io
println("Decoded UrlSafe: ${String(Base64.UrlSafe.decode(encodedURLSafe))}")
```