# How to encode a string with Base64 in Android?

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Base64 encoder and decoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322182/base64-encoder-and-decoder)

I am trying to encode a Url with Base64. Is there any way to encode it with Base64 in java/android?

I need something similar to base64_encode() function in PHP.

Comment: Is your input a string?  Due to your comment, it may well be, and in that case, the function you're looking for will not be exactly the same as `base64_encode` since strings are usually sequences of bytes in PHP and UTF-16 in Java.  This is why Android's Base64 requires byte arrays as input to the encoding function.

Comment: Input is string. The input was not an issue as I could convert the string easily suing getBytes(). However, outputting the result as a string was hard.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4322182/808940

Comment: I was not aware of the duplicate. Sorry.

Answer (score 19):

[Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) is part of the Android SDK from API level 8 onwards.

Comment: I am aware of that. However I needed simple function instead of converting from byte[] to string.

Comment: Base64.encodeToString("text".getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)

Comment: If you don't want the encoded output to wrap (i.e. contain the new line character) use Base64.encodeToString("text".getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);