# Base64 giving invalid arguments IOException on some devices

Tags: android, ioexception

I have Nexus 4 and it's giving me no problems. But when I tried my code on micromax canvas it threw an IOException "invalid arguments" while trying to save a file with an encoded filename.

I am using this line to convert the file name.

```
Base64.encodeToString(name.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT))
```

where `name` is the filename (example:hello.jpg).

Basically I want to convert the filename so that no one can even search it in sd card.

I think the problem is that the FAT file system supports filename length up to 42 characters but it is producing longer file names. I have also tried URL safe and no padding instead of default in Base64.

I need to know some alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

For work-around purpose, try to use a custom class for encoding and decoding

More info:
["IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64" while trying to use Base64 on Android 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066762/illegalargumentexception-bad-base-64-while-trying-to-use-base64-on-android-1)

Comment: my app is for only android 3.2+. The problem I think is the long filename produced by Base64
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ids.smartcalculator

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue in app but used a different method instead of base64

Comment: Hi, I removed the link to your app as it is not relevant to the question/answer at hand and to avoid being flagged as spam. However, to make this answer actually an answer, please describe your workaround here.

Comment: my workaround was to ignore encoding on the devices in which it will show error by catch(exception) :D

Answer (score 0):

i guess this should work

```
String filename = Base64.encodeToString(url.getBytes(), Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP);
```