# Can't get file uri from intent onActivityResult

Tags: android, file, onactivityresult

I would like to receive normal file path from `onActivityResult` like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.i("m", data!!.dataString!!)
            convertFileToString(data.dataString!!)

        }
    }
```

but I receive such error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18' does not exist
```

this exception comes from method which converts my file to string. This error points to this line:

```
try {
val data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file) // this line

} catch (e: IOException) {
e.printStackTrace()
}
```

This file exists also but I can't get it. I saw here some questions which suggest to get `REAL` path like this:

```
fun getPath(context:Context, uri:Uri):String {
  val result:String = null
  val proj = arrayOf<String>(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
  val cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, proj, null, null, null)
  if (cursor != null)
  {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
      val column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(proj[0])
      result = cursor.getString(column_index)
    }
    cursor.close()
  }
  if (result == null)
  {
    result = "Not found"
  }
  return result
}
```

but this method return such exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'Not found' does not exist
```

So, what I receive here `data!!.dataString!!`:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18
```

and what I receive here `Log.i("m",uri.path.toString())`:

```
/document/image:18
```

as I see this is not real path on which this pict was saved. Maybe someone knows where I made errors?)

### UPDATE

How I convert file to string:

```
fun convertFileToString(path: String) {
        //dialog.dismiss()
        val file = File(path)

        for (i in 0 until sn.array!!.size()) {
            val jsonObj = sn.array!![i].asJsonObject
            val nFile = jsonObj.get("filename").asString

            if (file.name == nFile) {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.message_about_attached__file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return
            }
        }

        try {
            val data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file)
            uploadFiles(File(path).name, Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: uri.data.toSting() will give you a nice content scheme. Use that. Dont try to get a file path. You dont need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to receive normal file path from onActivityResult like this:

My guess is that you are using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, or perhaps `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. You are getting a `content` `Uri`, which is exactly what those `Intent` actions are documented to return. Such a `Uri` might be backed by:

- A local file on external storage, which you probably cannot access on Android 10+
- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database
- A piece of content on the Internet that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- Content that is generated on the fly
- ...and so on

> this exception comes from method which converts my file to string

I assume that by "converts my file to string", you mean read the file contents in as a `String`. In that case:

- Get a `ContentResolver` by calling `getContentResolver()` on a `Context`, such as your `Activity`
- Call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`, passing in your `Uri`, to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`
- Call `reader().readText()` on the `InputStream` to get a `String` representing the file contents

Combined, that should be something like:

```
val string = data.data?.let { contentResolver.openInputStream(it).use { it.reader().readText() } }
```

Comment: what does contain variable `string`? content of file or what?

Comment: I added to my question method which converts my files to string, and here I have to send to it path in string

Comment: @Andrew: It will contain the text in the content identified by the `Uri`, or `null` if you did not get a `Uri` for some reason. You keep referring to "file" -- the sooner you stop thinking in terms of files, the more success you will have.

Comment: but then I need to convert this file to Base64, how I can use your solution for this task ?(

Comment: @Andrew: There are plenty of existing answers for how to convert a string to Base64, including ones that you can find using any major search engine. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7687912/115145). However, you may be better served then using `readBytes()` rather than `reader().readText()`, to get a `ByteArray` that you can then convert to Base64.