# Convert image to JSON

Tags: android, json, image

With my android app, I want to upload some text and image in a server. My problem is how to convert an image(from my phone) to a json object or json array. 
(I use 1.6 android sdk for my app)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you encode binary data as [Base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html). This allows to represent any kind of byte data as text. Consider the fact that the image is expanding by the ratio 4:3.

Edit: [How to convert a image into Base64 string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4830846/920511) (here you'll find a Base64 helper for API less than 8)

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the answer you're searching for. You can encode any byte array like that. You have to consider whether you want to expand binary data to a text representation.

Answer (score 2):

First you should be sure you want to do this. Perhaps there is a way to store the image as a plain file (or attachment?) on your server.

Otherwise get the byte data from the image. Then convert byte after byte into a huge string. Then the string could be stored as a property in your JSON object. You could use [Base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322182/base64-encoder-and-decoder) encoding too.