# Can i send images to android wear as String?

Tags: wear-os

I am learning how to develop for Android Wear,i want to send list of images to wear as String, because i can't send array of assets to wear.

Anybody know what i should do to get all of them ?

Comment: have you done any research?

Comment: Yes, I did.
Now I am sending images as an asset , and I want to send them as String.

Comment: when you say, as String, you mean, the image filepath or url? or the data "encoded" as a String?

Comment: i mean data encoded as String

Comment: you might want to take a lot at [java Base64 encoder and decoder question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4322202/4207875)