# Decode data in Android using android.util.base64

Tags: android, decoding

How to decode  org.apache.commons. codec.binery.Base64 
Method

```
String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(strToDecrypt)));
```

Using Android.util.Base64  ????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Base64 encoder and decoder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4322182/base64-encoder-and-decoder)